# Explain why I am getting error in 1 piece of code and not in the other one

Tags: java, eclipse

So I am making a JAVA program in eclipse which displays all the possible 3 digit positive numbers.I am using the stacking of *for loops* to do so.Here is the first time I tried it-

```
 public class go {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int firstNum = 0;firstNum<10;firstNum++){
        for (int secondNum = 0;secondNum<10;secondNum++){
            for(int thirdNum = 0;thirdNum<10;thirdNum++){

                System.out.println(firstNum+secondNum+thirdNum);
            }}}}}
```

The answer to that was a mix of different 1 digit and 2 digit numbers which repeat in a loop.It was just a really weird mix of ordered 1 or 2 digit numbers which is NOT what I wanted.Try it out yourself in eclipse if you have the time.

But then I tried this code-

```
public class go {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int firstNum = 0;firstNum<10;firstNum++){
        for (int secondNum = 0;secondNum<10;secondNum++){
            for(int thirdNum = 0;thirdNum<10;thirdNum++){

                System.out.println(firstNum+""+secondNum+""+thirdNum);
            }}}}}
```

Notice that I added blank spaces between the variables in the *println* statement.
And this time it worked perfectly!!Giving me every possible 3 digit positive integer.

Why didn't the 1st block of code work and why did the 2nd work?

Is it the way *println* looks at variables or what?
Please Help.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: @YassinHajaj i don't understand what you are saying. I checked the program 3-4 times and i didn't know that `println` could perform real addition.I thought that the **+** sign in `println` could only be used to concatenate whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add integers, as in `firstNum+secondNum+thirdNum`, you get the sum of these integers. That's what the `+` operator does for integers.

When you add String literals to the expression, as in `firstNum+""+secondNum+""+thirdNum`, the compiler performs `String` concatenation instead of addition.

Comment: Oh.1 more thing how do you highlight words in your answer?

Comment: @adi either with single quotes `like this` or with double stars **like this**

Comment: `ok` i get it **thank you** for your answer

Answer (score 0):

In the first piece of code, the integers got added. Whereas in the second piece of code it is a string.